# spark create map of list columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a master table as

```
+-----------+----------+-------------+
|  Age      | Gender   | date        |
+-----------+----------+-------------+
|  [1,2]    |   M      |  2021-01-01 | 
|  [11,13]  |   M      |  2021-01-10 | 
|  [4,5]    |   M      |  2021-01-15 |
|  [3]      |   F      |  2021-01-30 |
|  [7]      |   F      |  2021-02-20 |
|  [2]      |   F      |  2021-02-30 |
|  [6]      |   M      |  2021-02-20 |
```

Output needed is

1. map of date as key and values as list of age
2. the values in map need to extracted for limited days, I have taken 15 days for a example. It could be anything like 60, 90, 30.

```
+-----------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  Age      | Gender   | date                            |
+-----------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  [1,2]    |   M      |  [2021-01-01-->[1,2,11,13,4,5]] | 
|  [11,13]  |   M      |  [2021-01-10-->[1,2,11,13,4,5]] | 
|  [4,5]    |   M      |  [2021-01-15-->[1,2,11,13,4,5]] |
|  [3]      |   F      |  [2021-01-30-->[3]]             |
|  [7]      |   F      |  [2021-02-20-->[7,2]]           |
|  [2]      |   F      |  [2021-02-30-->[7.2]]           |
|  [6]      |   M      |  [2021-02-20-->[6]]             |
```

I have tried `spark.sql("""select Age,Gender,Map(date,age) as date from master""")`
but not able to find out how to control out based on number of days

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by windowing the dataframe based on the date limits in your example this is 15 days, after windowing group rows which match the criteria then group based on Gender and window group to collect ages.

## Working Example

1. Imports and Dataframe setup

```
from datetime import datetime
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

data = [([1, 2], "M", datetime.strptime("2021-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")),
 ([11, 13], "M", datetime.strptime("2021-01-10", "%Y-%m-%d")),
 ([4, 5], "M", datetime.strptime("2021-01-15", "%Y-%m-%d")),
 ([3], "F", datetime.strptime("2021-01-30", "%Y-%m-%d")),
 ([7], "F", datetime.strptime("2021-02-20", "%Y-%m-%d")),
 ([2], "F", datetime.strptime("2021-02-28", "%Y-%m-%d")),
 ([6], "M", datetime.strptime("2021-02-20", "%Y-%m-%d")), ]


df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("Age", "Gender", "date"))
```

2. Window defintion and acceptable condition to determine which rows can belong in the same group (`acceptable_window` variable in the code below captures this).

```
window_spec = Window.partitionBy("Gender").orderBy("date")
acceptable_window = 15
df1 = df.withColumn("date_diff", F.datediff(F.col("date"), F.lag("date").over(window_spec))).withColumn("date_group", F.when(F.col("date_diff").isNull(), 1).when(F.col("date_diff") > acceptable_window, 1).otherwise(0))
```

**Contents of df1**

```
+--------+------+-------------------+---------+----------+
|     Age|Gender|               date|date_diff|date_group|
+--------+------+-------------------+---------+----------+
|     [3]|     F|2021-01-30 00:00:00|     null|         1|
|     [7]|     F|2021-02-20 00:00:00|       21|         1|
|     [2]|     F|2021-02-28 00:00:00|        8|         0|
|  [1, 2]|     M|2021-01-01 00:00:00|     null|         1|
|[11, 13]|     M|2021-01-10 00:00:00|        9|         0|
|  [4, 5]|     M|2021-01-15 00:00:00|        5|         0|
|     [6]|     M|2021-02-20 00:00:00|       36|         1|
+--------+------+-------------------+---------+----------+
```

3. From `df1` determine which rows will fall into the same group, for this we sum `date_group` over our window.

```
df2 = df1.withColumn("date_window", F.sum(F.col("date_group")).over(window_spec))
```

**Contents of df2**

```
+--------+------+-------------------+---------+----------+-----------+
|     Age|Gender|               date|date_diff|date_group|date_window|
+--------+------+-------------------+---------+----------+-----------+
|     [3]|     F|2021-01-30 00:00:00|     null|         1|          1|
|     [7]|     F|2021-02-20 00:00:00|       21|         1|          2|
|     [2]|     F|2021-02-28 00:00:00|        8|         0|          2|
|  [1, 2]|     M|2021-01-01 00:00:00|     null|         1|          1|
|[11, 13]|     M|2021-01-10 00:00:00|        9|         0|          1|
|  [4, 5]|     M|2021-01-15 00:00:00|        5|         0|          1|
|     [6]|     M|2021-02-20 00:00:00|       36|         1|          2|
+--------+------+-------------------+---------+----------+-----------+
```

4. Use the `date_window` to flatten and collect `Age` that fall within this window and create a mapping between `date` and collected ages.

```
df2.withColumn("date", F.create_map(F.col("date"), F.flatten(F.collect_list("Age").over(Window.partitionBy("Gender", "date_window"))))).select("Age", "Gender", "date").show(200, False)
```

### Output

```
+--------+------+---------------------------------------------+
|Age     |Gender|date                                         |
+--------+------+---------------------------------------------+
|[3]     |F     |{2021-01-30 00:00:00 -> [3]}                 |
|[7]     |F     |{2021-02-20 00:00:00 -> [7, 2]}              |
|[2]     |F     |{2021-02-28 00:00:00 -> [7, 2]}              |
|[1, 2]  |M     |{2021-01-01 00:00:00 -> [1, 2, 11, 13, 4, 5]}|
|[11, 13]|M     |{2021-01-10 00:00:00 -> [1, 2, 11, 13, 4, 5]}|
|[4, 5]  |M     |{2021-01-15 00:00:00 -> [1, 2, 11, 13, 4, 5]}|
|[6]     |M     |{2021-02-20 00:00:00 -> [6]}                 |
+--------+------+---------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I have one question can you please explain more on , how value 36 occurs in date_diff column for 2021-02-20 date please

Comment: It's the [`date_diff`](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=15&m1=01&y1=2021&d2=20&m2=02&y2=2021) between `2021-02-20` and the previous date `2021-01-15` after partitioning by `Gender` and ordering by `date` ascending.